# Module 'amplify_auth_cognito' not found

Tags: flutter

[Flutter doctor -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vYvS.png)

[Error in xcode while archive ios app (.ipa format)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVhwN.png)

ERROR:

```
 CompileC /Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o /Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
                   cd /Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/ios
                   export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
                   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target armv7-apple-ios9.0 -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS\=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility\=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -iquote /Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSAuthCore/AWSAuthCore.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSCore/AWSCore.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSMobileClient/AWSMobileClient.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSPluginsCore/AWSPluginsCore.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Amplify/Amplify.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AmplifyPlugins/AmplifyPlugins.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController/DKImagePickerController.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/FMDB/FMDB.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/ObjectMapper/ObjectMapper.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/SDWebImage/SDWebImage.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/SwiftyGif/SwiftyGif.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Toast/Toast.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/amplify_auth_cognito/amplify_auth_cognito.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/amplify_core/amplify_core.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/file_picker/file_picker.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/fluttertoast/fluttertoast.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/image_cropper/image_cropper.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/image_picker/image_picker.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/jitsi_meet/jitsi_meet.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/libPhoneNumber-iOS/libPhoneNumber_iOS.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/libphonenumber/libphonenumber.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/libphonenumber_plugin/libphonenumber_plugin.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/path_provider/path_provider.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/share/share.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/shared_preferences/shared_preferences.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/sqflite/sqflite.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher/url_launcher.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/video_player/video_player.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/wakelock/wakelock.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/webview_cookie_manager/webview_cookie_manager.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/webview_flutter/webview_flutter.framework/Headers -I/Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources-normal/armv7 -I/Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSAuthCore -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSCore -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSMobileClient -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AWSPluginsCore -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Amplify -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AmplifyPlugins -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/DKPhotoGallery -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/FMDB -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/ObjectMapper -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/SDWebImage -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/SwiftyGif -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/TOCropViewController -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Toast -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/amplify_auth_cognito -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/amplify_core -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/amplify_flutter -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/file_picker -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/flutter_keyboard_visibility -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/fluttertoast -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/image_cropper -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/image_picker -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/jitsi_meet -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/libPhoneNumber-iOS -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/libphonenumber -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/libphonenumber_plugin -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/path_provider -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/share -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/shared_preferences -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/sqflite -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/video_player -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/wakelock -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/webview_cookie_manager -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/webview_flutter -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/ios/Pods/JitsiMeetSDK/Frameworks -F/Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/JitsiMeetSDK -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.dia -c /Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m -o /Users/srinivashvk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gghsdfalxcvhrdajecoisqmvxjpx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o
               /Users/srinivashvk/Desktop/proj-name/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'amplify_auth_cognito' not found
               @import amplify_auth_cognito;
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               1 error generated.
```

[For full log:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xm5huQz8dy61hwlPe1hEFIoqlGNvhtxF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: im facing the same problem now. did you managed to solve it ?

Comment: same here, did you slove the issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `amplify_auth_cognito` requires minimum deployment target version 11.0. Would you like to try the following steps?

1. Run `flutter create myapp`
2. Open `pubspec.yaml` and add `amplify_auth_cognito: ^0.2.4`
3. Run `flutter pub get`
4. Update Podfile and uncomment `platform :ios, '9.0'` and update it to `platform :ios, '11.0'` <----this is one key step
5. Run pod install
6. Open the newly generated `Runner.xcworkspace`
7. Update the iOS Deployment target to 11.0 for the relevant targets in Pods project. <----this is another key step
8. Run `flutter build ios` to create a release build

I end up with running the app in Xcode and it can be build and successfully.

Refer to the discussion in https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/881.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem trying to build a brand new app.

I found you need to delete the ios/ folder and recreate it.

So:

```
$ cd your-project-folder
$ rm -rf ios/
$ flutter create .
```

This re-creates the correct Podfile and seems to build correctly afterwards